# Copy from Google Sheets to Google Docs without Formatting Changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I created a Google Sheet where I need to copy some cells with formatting like Bold and Italic. I have to copy that each cells with formats to Google Docs without changing its format. Here is the code that I used but it only copies the data without the formats. I don't want it to format because sometimes it depends on the writer on how he formats the text, so all I need is to copy it as is without changing the formats. How should I copy it with the formatting within the cells?

```
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sourceSS.setActiveSheet(sourceSS.getSheetByName(tabName));
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(target);

  var headertxt = ss.getRange('A32').getValues();
  var subjtxt = "Subject: ";
  var subjtitle = ss.getRange('D33').getValues();
  var copytxt = ss.getRange('D34:D').getValues();
  var rowCnt = copytxt.filter(String).length;

  var rowStart = 34;
  var txt = ss.getRange(rowStart, 4, rowStart+rowCnt, 1).getValues();

  var body = newDoc.getBody();

  var header = body.appendParagraph(headertxt+'\n');
  header.setBold(false);
  header.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4);


  var subj = body.appendParagraph(subjtxt + subjtitle +'\n');
  subj.setBold(true);


  var table = body.appendTable(txt);
  table.setBorderWidth(0);
  table.setBold(false);

  var newPage = body.appendPageBreak();
```

I am actually trying to apply it to the var table since it is the one that contains cells that has text formatting.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot see the vision of the result you expect. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and sample result you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: The vision is to copy the cell as is. Each cell contains text with bold and italics and some regular text but when it is pasted to Google Doc it removes the formatting. I need to copy them as is without changing the text formatting from the cells.

Comment: Here's a screenshot. The Google Sheet cell, when it is copied to Google Docs, the result is the red arrow. Where it should be, the result should be the green arrow where it should not be changed. Hope this helps. https://drive.google.com/file/d/11oFG4zDJR4WqyAfAuTcv9M4x-6DtwCGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot open your shared file. But I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: nope it was not yet answered, still not able to deliver it. :(

Comment: can you check on this https://drive.google.com/file/d/11oFG4zDJR4WqyAfAuTcv9M4x-6DtwCGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could open the file. But unfortunately, I cannot understand where are the values of the image in the Spreadsheet. And also, I cannot understand whether the cells are merged. Unfortunately, when I cannot correctly understand about OP's situation, I cannot propose the modification points. This is due to my poor understanding. I apologize for this.

Comment: values in spreadsheet is in var copytxt = ss.getRange('D34:D').getValues();
yes its a merged cells D to H

what is OP's?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `OP's situation`, I used it as `your situation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote two functions. The first gets the contents of a cell as rich text and stores the text and attributes as separate runs in an array of objects. There is one object for each run. getRichTextValue is documented here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value

```
function getRichTextCell(fdbkRgA1) {
  console.log('Begin getRichTextCell input fdbkRgA1: ', fdbkRgA1 );
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const inRng = sheet.getRange(fdbkRgA1);

  let richText = ss.getRange(fdbkRgA1).getRichTextValue(); 
  let thisText = richText.getText(); 
  // console.log('Cell content: ' + thisText);
  let runsArr = richText.getRuns(); 
  // console.log('runs length: ' + runsArr.length );
  
  let rtObjArr = [];
  for ( i = 0 ; i < runsArr.length ; i++ )    { 

    // get the style of this section of text, between startIndex and endIndex 
    let run = runsArr[i]; 
    let runtext = run.getText();
    let color = run.getTextStyle().getForegroundColor();
    let font = run.getTextStyle().getFontFamily();
    let fontsize = run.getTextStyle().getFontSize();
    let startIndex = run.getStartIndex(); 
    let endIndex = run.getEndIndex(); 
    let styleBold = run.getTextStyle().isBold(); 
    let styleItalic = run.getTextStyle().isItalic();
    let stylesThru = run.getTextStyle().isStrikethrough();
    let styleUline = run.getTextStyle().isUnderline();
    // console.log('i: ', i, ' Start Idx: ', startIndex, 
    //                       ' End Idx: ', endIndex, 
    //                       ' Text: ', runtext, 
    //                       ' Bold?: ', styleBold, 
    //                       ' Color: ', color, 
    //                       ' Font: ', font, 
    //                       ' Size: ', fontsize, 
    //                       ' Italic?: ', styleItalic, 
    //                       ' Strikethru?: ', stylesThru, 
    //                       ' Underline?: ', styleUline);
    rtObjArr.push ({
                    'StartIdx' : startIndex, 
                    'EndIdx' : endIndex, 
                    'Text' : runtext, 
                    'Bold' : styleBold, 
                    'Color' : color, 
                    'Font' : font, 
                    'Size' : fontsize, 
                    'Italic' : styleItalic, 
                    'Strikethru' : stylesThru, 
                    'Underline' : styleUline
                  });

  } 
  
  return rtObjArr;
}
```

The second function receives the object with rich text and attribute runs and adds it either at the top or the bottom of an existing document.

```
function setRichTextDoc(rtObjArr, stuDoc, TorB, docTit) {
  console.log('Begin setRichTextDoc input docTit: ', docTit);
  
  let numRuns = rtObjArr.length;
  // console.log('numRuns: ', numRuns);
  if ( numRuns === 0 ) {
    console.log('No feedback found for student doc.' + docTit +
                '\nSKIPPING' );
    ui.alert('No feedback found for student doc.' + docTit +
             '\nSKIPPING');
    return;
  }
  
  let theTxt, runtext, color, font, fontsize, para,
      styleBold, styleItalic, stylesThru, styleUline;
 
  if ( TorB === 'BOTTOM' )  {
    // console.log('begin before stuff BOTTOM');
    stuDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
    para = stuDoc.appendParagraph('Feedback on Current Draft');
    para.setForegroundColor('#000000')
        .setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
        .setBold(true); 
    para = stuDoc.appendParagraph("")  
  }    else    {
    // console.log('begin before stuff TOP');
    para = stuDoc.insertParagraph(0, "")
    stuDoc.insertHorizontalRule(1);
    para = stuDoc.insertParagraph(2, 'Final Comments');      
    para.setForegroundColor('#000000')
        .setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
        .setBold(true);
    para = stuDoc.insertParagraph(3, "")  
  }
      
  for ( i = 0 ; i < numRuns ; i++ ) {
    console.log ('i: ', i, ' stringify input object\n', JSON.stringify(rtObjArr[i]) );
    runtext  = rtObjArr[i].Text;
    color = rtObjArr[i].Color;
    font = rtObjArr[i].Font;
    fontsize = rtObjArr[i].Size; 
    styleBold = rtObjArr[i].Bold; 
    styleItalic = rtObjArr[i].Italic;
    stylesThru = rtObjArr[i].Strikethru;
    styleUline = rtObjArr[i].Underline;
    
    if ( TorB === 'BOTTOM' )  {
      // console.log('begin rich text BOTTOM');
      theTxt = para.appendText(runtext);  //  Exception: Cannot insert an empty text element.
      // theTxt = stuDoc.appendText(runtext);  //  Err: TypeError: stuDoc.appendText is not a function
      // theTxt = stuDoc.appendParagraph(runtext);  //  runs but nothing stored
      theTxt.setFontFamily(font)
            .setFontSize(fontsize)
            .setForegroundColor(color)
            .setBold(styleBold) 
            .setItalic(styleItalic) 
            .setStrikethrough(stylesThru)
            .setUnderline(styleUline);
    }    else    {
      // console.log('begin rich text TOP');
      theTxt = para.appendText(runtext);
      theTxt.setFontFamily(font)
            .setFontSize(fontsize)
            .setForegroundColor(color)
            .setBold(styleBold) 
            .setItalic(styleItalic) 
            .setStrikethrough(stylesThru)
            .setUnderline(styleUline);
    }

    // console.log ('i: ', i, ' finished' );
  }
  
  if ( TorB === 'BOTTOM' )  {
    console.log('begin after stuff BOTTOM');
    para = stuDoc.appendParagraph('Create Your Next Draft Below');
    para.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
    .setBold(true);
    stuDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  }    else    {
    console.log('begin after stuff TOP');
    stuDoc.insertHorizontalRule(4);
    stuDoc.insertParagraph(5, '');
  }
  
  console.log('End setRichTextDoc');
}
```

The code preserves new lines and left horizontal alignment even though these are not available attributes.
I could not have figured this out without the help of @Chris [Google Docs Script: appendText/insertText Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855672/google-docs-script-appendtext-inserttext-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the ranges that contain the values you want, you can use methods like [`getBackground`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground), [`getFontWeight`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontweight), [`getFontStyle`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontstyle), [`getFontSize`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsize), [`getFontColors`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolors) to retrieve the information you need to replicate.

Then you can use [`setAttributes`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setattributesattributes) to replicate the values you got when inserting the paragraphs into the Document.

Comment: But the ranges contain combined text with formats and without formats,

Comment: One cell contains with bold text, with italics and regular text which is without italics and bold. Need to copy them as is. setAttributes is set to a specific cell which it converts all text to bold.

Comment: you have to treat the array of styles and insert the data on your paragraphs accordingly.

Comment: how to do it? I am not that familiar with array, sorry

Comment: @Tanaike this is not a solution. I have teacher comments in a spreadsheet. Each cell contains one or more sentences with many styles: bold, italic, new line, font size changes, anything.  When copied from the sheet to the doc all formatting is lost. Remember how teachers mark things up? You should have done <bold>this</bold> not <bold>that</bold>. new line more advice...